# Part time visiting researcher in UK while doing postdoc in Germany

Tags: postdocs, united-kingdom, academic-life, germany

Currently working as a scientific employee in Germany and have an opportunity to work as a visiting researcher in the UK(top university). Is it possible to work at a place that considers the working hour's law?

In Germany, after having a permanent residence holder, is it possible to get work VISA for UK?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Is it possible to work at a place that considers the working hour's law?"? Do you mean is there any sort of a protection/law/gauarantee that you will not be required to work more than a reasonable/contractual amount (8/h day or similar)?

Comment: @penelope in terms of VISA and regulation

Comment: It might matter how this is organized; rules for freelancing while being employed in Germany are different from those holding a second job. - In any case, talk to your boss: If I would learn that one of my people were working on the side somewhere else without telling me, I would be rather upset.

Comment: Note that the phrase "visiting researcher" can often mean that you **don't** get paid by the hosting institute...

Comment: @user151413, are you suggesting going for freelancing instead of a side job? If yes, what are the rules?

Comment: @RohanVaidya I don't know for sure; but if you are freelancing, there is no fixed working hours for the other job. There is still constraints on how much you are allowed to work on the other job (typically 8h/week), but this might be harder to quantify. Also, there's (soft) limits on how much you can earn - it cannot be unreasonably higher than your primary salary (per hour).

Comment: What does the sentence "Is it possible to work at a place that considers the working hour's law" mean? Perhaps to guide the question a bit, in general, a visiting researcher at a UK institution must be paid by their overseas institution. As such, the UK institution has no involvement in pay.